# jQuery: how do I remove an Element from the DOM tree?

Tags: jquery

my HTML:

```
<li class="accept  accepted" name="javascript_required" style="display: block; " id="accept">
            <div id="accept-text" style="display: block; ">
                Contract was Accepted
            </div>
            <a href="/view/close_contract/89?status=2" rel="facebox">Accept This Controct</a></li>
```

then my jQuery that i'm trying in the webkit console:

```
$j('li#accept').remove('a');
```

the above command reterns

```
Object
> 0: HTMLLIElement
> context: HTMLDocument
  length: 1
> prevObject: Object
  selector: "li#accept"
> __proto__: Object
```

After entering the command, the `anchor` remains in the DOM =(

Comment: FYI: the `name` attribute isn't valid on an `LI` element.

Comment: you sure? my javascript taht uses the attribute works =p

Comment: It’s not valid in HTML 4 Strict or HTML 5, but it’s valid in older specs. Also, you can read an attribute from JavaScript whether its valid according to the HTML spec or not. It looks like you’re misusing the `name` attribute to attach arbitrary data to elements. That isn’t recommended. Use HTML 5 data attributes for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$('li#accept > a').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

This http://interestingwebs.blogspot.com/2009/04/jquery-selectors-samples.html describes selectors in jQuery - it's a really nice one.

I would use:

```
$("#accept > a").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, try `$('li.accept').remove('a');`

Comment: Actually his selector looks fine. If you scroll over the id of the li element is accept. I thought similarly at first as well.

Comment: DOH, right. well your answer is marked as accepted now so that's good. Do you know why his code wouldn't work then ? Seems based on the documentation it should have ?